# How to get a name of created table with regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a file with the following content:

```
create_table "animals", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
end
```

The most interesting and confusing part to me is that using regexp I have to somehow fetch name of the table.

For example:

```
animals
```

How can I do this using regular expressions?

Comment: Read about [*capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes", but presumably that's not the answer you are looking for.  So what is your actual question?  Which part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: `/create_table "(\S*)"/g`  [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/xZ6rI5/2)

Comment: @StevenDoggart I'm interested in implementation. I haven't dealt with regular expressions a lot, thus I consider myself as a noob and I came here to ask for a help. When I see answer I try to look up its meaning and grasp the idea of how it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

```
^create_table\s*"([^"]+)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/kI7yZ1/1

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{12}                    any character except \n (12 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    001                      '001'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    005                      '005'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Nice! I might however lose the start anchor. It might not be first on the line. And maybe allow for single quoted string. i.e. `create_table\s*(["'])((?:(?!\1).)+)\1`. It'll move the name of the table to capture group 2 though.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = subject.scan(/create_table "(.*?)"/i)
```

---

```
create_table "(.*?)"
Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks
Match the character string “create_table "” literally (case insensitive) «create_table "»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “"” literally «"»
```